# How can Pylance get the type annotation of a dynamically defined class?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

```py
from types import ModuleType
from typing import Any, Dict, Tuple, Type, TypeVar

from . import default

_T = TypeVar("_T", bound=type)

class settings_meta(type):
    def __new__(
        cls: Type[_T],
        name: str,
        bases: Tuple[type, ...],
        namespace: Dict[str, Any],
        settings: ModuleType,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> _T:
        from inspect import ismodule

        namespace = {
            key: val
            for key, val in vars(settings).items()
            if not key.startswith("__") and not ismodule(val)
        }
        namespace["__annotations__"] = {
            key: val
            for key, val in vars(settings)["__annotations__"].items()
            if key in namespace.keys()
        }
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwrags: Any) -> Any:
        raise RuntimeError

class settings(metaclass=settings_meta, settings=default):
    ...
```

I want to use `settings` class. But Pylance informs me of `reportGeneralTypeIssues`.

Because annotations has been called, but Pylance does not recognize it.

I know that this is simply solved by turning it off. *Python › Analysis: Type Checking Mode*

But I don't want to turn it off.

How can Pylance get the type annotation of a dynamically defined class?

Comment: I have [this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78048847/13944524). If the settings were known in advance, we could use `if TYPE_CHECKING:` and define their annotation inside the body but this is not the case.