# How to dynamically provide arguments to a class __init__ function based on attributes?

Tags: python, oop, metaprogramming

How do tools like `dataclasses` and `pydantic` create the `__init__()` functions for the classes they create?

I know I can use these tools but I want to learn how to use the python metaprogramming to parse my class and create a dynamic init function based on attributes and their types.

an example:

```py
class MyClass:
  x: int
  y: str | None
  z: float = 0.1

  # I don't want to manually make this
  def __init__(self, x: int, y: str | None, z: float = 0.1):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
```

Is it possible to do something similar using metaclasses and type annotations?

Comment: [Code for the decorator](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8a5731e7db46b036de8a7447864127900e2d3ade/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1238), and the [code for modifying the class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8a5731e7db46b036de8a7447864127900e2d3ade/Lib/dataclasses.py#L921).

Comment: [Code that creates the `__init__` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cbe809dfa94385bacaa24beee3976ba77a395589/Lib/dataclasses.py#L568).

Comment: I can parse through state-of-the-art code and eventually understand it but I suppose its more a question of how tooling would look at that metacode and determine the type structures and signatures and how I can write that stuff too

Answer (score 2):

There are two main approaches:

1. Decorator
2. Metaclass

---

The idea for `dataclass` is that you need to somehow get all the annotations and *build* that method manually from a string(I'll show you). In this scenario you have the class object created.

Available tools are:

- `typing` module has `get_type_hints` function.
- you can access the class' attributes using `__dict__`.
- you can use `exec()` to dynamically create objects. ([dataclass literally does this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cbe809dfa94385bacaa24beee3976ba77a395589/Lib/dataclasses.py#L473))

```py
from typing import get_type_hints


def my_dataclass(cls):
    fn_definition = "def __init__(self, "

    # building the first line of __init__
    for annotation, type_ in get_type_hints(cls).items():
        type_name = type_.__name__ if hasattr(type_, "__name__") else str(type_)
        fn_definition += f"{annotation}: {type_name}"
        if annotation in cls.__dict__:
            fn_definition += f" = {cls.__dict__[annotation]}"
        else:
            fn_definition += ", "
    fn_definition += "):\n"

    # building the body of __init__
    for annotation in get_type_hints(cls):
        fn_definition += f"\tself.{annotation} = {annotation}\n"
    print(fn_definition)

    # creating the function object:
    namespace = {}
    exec(fn_definition, {}, namespace)
    __init__ = namespace["__init__"]
    cls.__init__ = __init__
    return cls


@my_dataclass
class MyClass:
    x: int
    y: str | None
    z: float = 0.1


obj = MyClass(10, 20)
print(obj.x)
print(obj.y)
print(obj.z)
```

output:

```
def __init__(self, x: int, y: str | None, z: float = 0.1):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

10
20
0.1
```

Of course this is a naive approach and has some problems but it gives you the overview of the idea. `dataclass` and `pydantic`(which I'll show after) do a lot of other stuff as well.

Another approach which is used by Pydantic is using a metaclass. The difference is that with decorators, the class is created first and then you extract the information you want but in metaclasses the information is available in the `namespace` parameter of the `__new__` "*before creating that class*": (I won't go to implement it because the concept is the same as before)

```py
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        type_hints = namespace["__annotations__"]
        default_values = {k: namespace[k] for k in type_hints if k in namespace}
        print(type_hints)
        print(default_values)


class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    x: int
    y: str | None
    z: float = 0.1
```

output:

```
{'x': 'int', 'y': 'str | None', 'z': 'float'}
{'z': 0.1}
```

Now you can now check the actual source codes and follow their implementation.

Also note that there are many helpful functions in [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module that let's you inspect many information from objects in runtime.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you